# How to get subjective answer from user

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

Is it possible to get a subjective answer from user?
Here is sample conversation that I am trying to build,

1. User: "I found a bug." => [triggers 'bug report' intent]
2. Agent: "Can you explain the problem?"
3. User: "App crashes everytime when I ask about xxx." => ['bug report follow-up' intent fails]

I wanted to catch the user answer, line #3. Even if I setup correct follow-up context, 'Default Fallback' or other intent came out and handle the user response. It seems there is no intent that can handle this kind of user query. I could not put 'Training phrase' because the answer can be any sentence. Maybe I can ask user to answer like "[The problem is] xxxxx", or "xxxxx [is not working], but it is not natural and limit the user answer.
If there is a workaround to catch whole user query right after some intent, please share with me. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make 2 intents for this, lets say `bug-1` and `bug-2`.

In the `bug-1`, provide **found a bug** in `training phrases` and **bug** in `output context` and **Can you explain the problem?** in `response`.
Now in `bug-2`, give **bug** as `input context`, change training phrases to `template mode` and give `@sys.any` in that and give some parameter name. Ex: `@sys.any:bug`.

Now bug will contain the entire user query.

[image]

**EDIT 1:**
By using `@sys.any:bug`, the the user query will be stored in the `parameter named bug`, which we can use in response by referencing $bug. See the pic below for clarification.
[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! [at]sys.any did the trick. However, I don't understand ":bug" thing. Even if I put [at]sys.any:bug, I got query: {"any":"text"}. Reference link to System Entities https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/system-entities#date-ko-v2

Answer (score 1):

The syntax and/or process wasn't entirely clear in the answer by sid8491 so I've shown the exact process that worked for me (in August 2020).

1.) Manually enter the following in the "Actions and parameters":

[image: actions and paremeters]

`the_user_input` is the variable name, make it anything you like)

2. You now create a single training intent:

[image: Setting up a wildcard entry]

I was able to match an entire user input string by typing the symbol `@` as the only training phrasing, selecting the text and choosing `@sys.any:the_user_input` from the menu that pops up.

I haven't confirmed if the training phrase HAS to be `@` but I think it does.

If you do step 2 without step one dialogflow will warn:

[image: warning]

It's warning you that matching an entire phrase can have unexpected side-effects (like other intents not matching anymore), you have to setup follow-on intents and fallback intents to create exceptions to this "match whole line" rule.

You can't capture parameters in a fallback but you can capture the line on a parent intent and use follow-up intents to do additional matching and exceptions.

I haven't tested this yet but if your design calls for capturing the line in a parent context and handling cases in a follow-up intent the syntax for using `the_user_input` in a response should be something like:

Hi, you said "`#parent_context_name:the_user_input`"